# Get all tweets and re tweets from Twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

I am working with Twitter API and I am stuck on a problem. My problem is I cannot get all tweets and retweets from Twitter in response. I have read the documentation on twitter [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html). They have mentioned that `This method can only return up to 3,200 of a user’s most recent Tweets. Native retweets of other statuses by the user is included in this total, regardless of whether include_rts is set to false when requesting this resource.`

But when I hitting `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxxx&count=968`, I am getting only 198 records in response where I have 968 tweets.

So Please help me to how I can get all records from Twitter in response and what parameters I have to pass in URL soi can get all tweets and retweets?

Please suggest me for the better approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **[count  - optional](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/api-reference/get-statuses-user_timeline.html)**
>   Specifies the number of Tweets to try and retrieve, up
>   to a maximum of 200 per distinct request. The value of count is best
>   thought of as a limit to the number of Tweets to return because
>   suspended or deleted content is removed after the count has been
>   applied. We include retweets in the count, even if include_rts is not
>   supplied. It is recommended you always send include_rts=1 when using
>   this API method.

From twitter api you can get 200 tweets in a single request. you have to make another request to get the next set of tweets. you are getting 198 because retweets are also counted as a tweet.

> **[The max_id parameter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/timelines/guides/working-with-timelines)**
>
> The solution to the issue described above is to use a technique for working with streams of data called cursoring.
>   Instead of reading a timeline relative to the top of the list (which
>   changes frequently), an application should read the timeline relative
>   to the IDs of Tweets it has already processed. This is achieved
>   through the use of the max_id request parameter.
>
> To use max_id correctly, an application’s first request to a timeline
>   endpoint should only specify a count. When processing this and
>   subsequent responses, keep track of the lowest ID received. This ID
>   should be passed as the value of the max_id parameter for the next
>   request, which will only return Tweets with IDs lower than or equal to
>   the value of the max_id parameter.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I fetched first 200 tweets in single request first and then i again make request and pass tweet id of last array in `since_id` parameter. But i got same result in output. Here is my URL `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=xxxxx&since_id=here-last-tweet-id`, please help me where i am doing wrong and what will be the exact parameter for get next tweets?

Comment: i have updated the answer. and  the `since_id` returns the tweets starting from that id only, so thats why you are getting the same results again. somehow you will have to calculate the previous 200th id. so instead of that we can use `max_id`. if this helped you, a thumbs up will be good

Comment: Thanks for solution.